# Is it possible to use crashlytics without firebase?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm new with Java and Android apps, that's why my questions might look strange, but...

I've migrated my application from Firebase to MongoDB, that's why I'm thinking about replacing Crashlytics with something else.

Here I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to continue using Crashlytics with MongoDB (without Firebase)?
   Btw, currently, I'm writing into DB via API calls.
2. Are there any analogues which might replace Crashlytics (again, without Firebase)?

I was trying to find any solution to how it might be integrated with Mongo (or without Firebase), but all topics about Crashlytics are related to Firebase.

Comment: I've answered #1 below. #2 is asking for a technology recommendation, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. So I recommend removing that question, and spending a few Google searches on finding alternatives if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics is part of Firebase nowadays, but you can use Crashlytics without using any of the other Firebase products.

Whether you use Crashlytics on its own or combined with other Firebase products, you can also use other 3rd party products such as MongoDB.